# P&L: Sum subgroups of a division (revenue/expense) and then subtract to get net profit

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to create a basic P&L.  I've put together the following table:

[image]

I'd like to sum up Total Expenses and Revenues by year and then subtract the two to get Net profit.  I know I can use the show totals section to see Total Revenue and Expenses, but I want to learn the principal of summing up subgroups of dimensions (in this case the dimension is Category, and the subgroups are Revenue and Expense).

Ultimately, I'd like to insert a net profit at the bottom of the table.  I've tried many LOD expressions to no avail.

The net profit should be:

[image]

dropbox link to workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyjo1urzjke1p5x/Animals.twb?dl=0

Comment: can you attach work book?

Comment: @Srikanth Uploaded a dropbox link to workbook